# Password not recognized

Tags: seed

Even though I know the password is correct, it is not working. I have my private keys on my ledger. Can I install a new wallet and use my ledger seed phrases? I never got seed phrases from Iota.

Answer (score -1):

If you have your private keys, you can simply reinstall. The password is part of the ledger software and has nothing to do with the tangle.